# CouchDB cookie authentication does not work with jQuery

Tags: jquery, cookies, couchdb

I have a CouchDB server on the localhost (`127.0.0.1`) with CORS enabled and I am using the couch jQuery library to access it from a page served by an Apache server. I try to authenticate as follows:

```
$.couch.urlPrefix = "http://127.0.0.1:5984";    
    $.couch.login({
    name:     "user1",
    password: "user1password",                          
    success: function(data) {    
        $.couch.session({
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(data));             
             }                 
         });    
     }
 });
```

`$.couch.login()$` works (I receive an `AuthSession` cookie and the response `{"ok":true,"name":"user1","roles":["operator"]}`). Issue is: any subsequent  request that requires the user to be logged in fails, because the cookie is not being sent by the browser (Chrome/Firefox, also on different machines). Obviously then, response to `$.couch.session()` is as if no user is logged in: `{"ok":true,"userCtx":{"name":null,"roles":[]},"info":{"authentication_db":"_users","authentication_handlers":["oauth","cookie","default"]}}`. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed the problem after realising that most browsers do not set cookies that originated on a different domain. The de-facto reference for the CouchDB JQuery plugin [here](http://bradley-holt.com/2011/07/couchdb-jquery-plugin-reference/) mentions this in the beginning of the article. I chose to set a reverse proxy in Apache, such that all requests directed to `127.0.0.1:80/couch/` would be translated to `127.0.0.1:5984`, where the CouchDB server resides. The response from CouchDB, containing the session authentication cookie, will be translated by apache, such that the client will see the answer as coming from the original destination.

To setup a reverse proxy create a file in `/etc/apache2/sites-available` called 001-couch.conf and paste the code below. Then create a symbolic link to this file in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled`. Default reverse proxies may interfere with your new configuration. To remove them, you can safely delete the other symbolic links.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
   AllowEncodedSlashes On
   ProxyRequests Off
   KeepAlive Off

   <Proxy *>
      Order deny,allow
      Deny from all
      Allow from all
   </Proxy>

   #--- Filter to CouchDB ---
   # Translate request to CouchDB
   ProxyPass /couch/ http://localhost:5984/ 
   # Translate response from CouchDB 
   ProxyPassReverse /couch/ http://localhost:5984/ 

   ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/couchdb.localhost-error_log
   CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/couchdb.localhost-access_log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried your code on my machine and it was working. So the only reason i could find, was that your [configuration](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/config/auth.html#authentication-configuration) must be wrong! Perhaps you can give some further informations about this?!

Comment: It was a cross-origina issue. I will post the answer shortly. Thank you.